# how to grab multiple (int) from title

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm using `$intVariable=(int)$_GET[var1];`

to output and select a variable in mysql records i.e `/myfile.php?cat=5` selects different results.

I am dealing with a dropdown from SQL so need to output a list based on selected ID's.. so I need to have something like `/myfile.php?var1=X&var2=Y`

I'm actually using a bit of JavaScript too, so unsure whether it's PHP or JS I need to adjust to grab another variable.

This code + some PHP currently outputs the selected ID of my selection in the title bar..

```
    function reload(form)
    {
    var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
    self.location='myfile.php?var1=' + val ;
    }
```

How do I achieve this multi tier structure getting 2 variables from the title, so I can use multiple variable to assign in my MYSQL selects. have tier dropdown lists

Comment: Looks like you might have to modify both, mind posting that PHP?

Comment: if you have a lot of myfile.php?var= to pass you can use something like this: myfile.php?var=1,2,3,4,5,6 and then you can use php to split them using explode function.

Comment: Let me know if my answer needs more detail, are you using jquery?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/AAWT3Pph - here's the php which deal with only 2 dropdowns. My second dropdown is out of this loop, but with global variables it should be fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what exact answer your looking for, but to fix your function to add more vars:

```
function reload(form)
    {
    var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
    self.location='myfile.php?var1=' + val + '&var2=' + val2;
    }
```

In general:

what your setting there is the GET parameters in the URL, so for example to set the variables "name" and "age" you would do:

```
http://www.example.com?name=bob&age=17
```

Where name is bob and age is 17

The other way people do it is through html arrays, so:

```
http://www.example.com?people[]=bob&people[]=fred
```

On the php side, $_GET['people'] will return an array with the two strings bob and fred.

If your using javascript to construct the url, you need to js to create a url like the one above, I'm guessing it should return

```
self.location='myfile.php?var1='+val+'&var2='+val2
```

When your reloading the form, to retain the selected drop down, you need to do one of two things

JS: Recommended

```
$('#mySelect').val(val2)
```

or in the php

```
if($optionvalue == $val2){$selected = "selected"}
echo "<option value=\"$optionvalue\" $selected>myoption</option>"
```

Comment: Hey, this does work but when I select the second category it doesn't keep it in the dropdown, but outputs it into the title.. Check this out. http://pastebin.com/25DGavwV

Comment: Without reading the code, I'd say you need to get which option has been selected. ie $('#mySelect').val(val2).

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you need is both PHP and javascript i think. You should pass another variable

```
function reload(form)
{
var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
var val2 = //get the value for var 2
self.location='myfile.php?var1=' + val +'&var2='+ val2 ;
}
```

and then get it in php

```
 $intValue2= (int)$_GET['var2']
```

and use it for mysql

Comment: do I have to have a onchange=\"reload(this.form) form the second variable?